# Calculation of Running time of array when size increase by constant

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I am learning data structure and running time calculation. I got a problem to understand the running time calculation of increasing the size of the array.

1) if we increase the size of the array by constant.

```
N=4 will be N0  

N=8 will be N0+c 

N=12 will be N0+2c 
.
.
No+kc

N=N0 +kc 
N=N0+kc

k=(N−N0 )/c 
k=(N−N0)/c

 Running time= N0 k+c(1+2+,...,k) 
N0 k+c(1+2+,...,k)

N0 k+ck(k+1)/2 which is equal to  O(N2)
```

Anyone please help me to understand the final calculation of running time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final step in your analysis above makes use of a well-known [summation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation).

[image]

Unwrapping `N` from this expression in `k` yields an upper bound on the asymptotic behaviour of your algorithm as `O(N^2)`.

[image]

Note that in practice, the term *"running time"* can be somewhat misleading, as the actual running *time* for a algorithm with regard to a growing entity (such as the size of an array) is not necessarily directly corresponding to the *time complexity* or *asymptotic behaviour* of the algorithm (depending on, e.g., how a specific system treats and moves big data structures in memory and so on). We're really only interested in the complexity, as it gives yields an estimation of how the algorithm will behave when input data grows large, relatively speaking. Perhaps apples and apples, but in this sense, I believe *"running time"* a bit too open to misinterpretations; e.g., a reader of our complexity analysis might believe we're actually stating a measure in SI time units for how long the algorithm will run, whereas in fact we're only presenting bounds on the *behaviour* of the algorithm in the asymptotic limit of it.

---

Some curiosa: this summation rule above plays a central part in the (rumoured) story of how famous mathematician Gauss, as a child of age 8, summed the numbers of 1 to 100 on-the-fly given such an assignment by his teacher, meanwhile his classmates did their best to (slowly) add these number by number.

- [Techniques for Adding the Numbers 1 to 100](http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/).